# Network unreachable when address is IPv6 in Buildroot

Tags: linux, routes, ipv6, buildroot

I created a custom Buildroot 2015.01 distribution w/ 3.10.0 Linux Kernel with enabled IPv6 support in the Toolchain and the uClibc library.

There is a strange behaviour that takes place when trying to contact any IPv6 routed address, for example:

```
# wget google.com
Connecting to google.com ([2a00:1450:4002:809::200e]:80)                        
wget: can't connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

But, if I try the same thing on a non-IPv6 address, everything works correctly:

```
# wget abc.com                                                                                                                
Connecting to abc.com (199.181.132.250:80)                                                                                    
Connecting to abc.go.com (23.21.209.55:80)                                                                                    
index.html           100% |*******************************| 46408   0:00:00 ETA
```

This is the IPv6 kernel routing table:

```
# route -A inet6                                                                                                                       
Destination                                 Next Hop                                Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface             
::1/128                                     ::                                      U     0      0        1 lo                
fe80::20a:a5ff:fe12:3446/128                ::                                      U     0      0        1 lo                
fe80::/64                                   ::                                      U     256    0        0 eth0              
ff02::1:ffdc:adf/128                        ::                                      UC    0      1        0 eth0              
ff02::1:fff4:5e3d/128                       ::                                      UC    0      1        0 eth0              
ff00::/8                                    ::                                      U     256    0        0 eth0
```

IPv4 one:

```
# route -A inet
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                                 
default         192.168.0.230   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0                                                  
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing standard **wget** instead of the Busybox's integrated one.

As it seems our internal network was not IPv6 capable and Busybox's wget stopped when it couldn't reach the destination. Standard wget, instead, falls back to the IPv4 address, completing the download.

EDIT: apart from our network, seems Busybox's wget has some issues